# How to partition the states of a DFA having a dead state during minimisation of the same

Tags: automata, computation-theory, dfa

When we want to minimise a DFA,at first we partition the final and non-final states.Then we divide those states into several more partitions until all the states in each partition belong to the same equivalence class.Now my question is suppose we have a dead state in the dfa then should it go to the partition of non-final states or to a separate partition(containg only the dead state)?Also please tell me whether that dead state should be counted as one of the states in the minimised dfa?

Answer (score 4):

The dead state goes into the set of non-final states, because it's not an accepting state.

You treat dead states just like any other (non-final) state during the minimization algorithm. When you're done, if your DFA needs a dead state at all, it should have a dead state as one of its states. If other states in the DFA have no paths to any accepting state, they're effectively dead and will be merged with the dead state during minimization.

Some regular languages require dead states, but the algorithms are "smart" enough to ensure that they're included.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just one query I have that since we are considering the dead state along with other non-final states in the same equivalence class what would be the ultimate position of the dead state after all subdivisions of the equiv. classes have been over.Two or more states residing in the same equiv. block must be merged to a single state in the minimised dfa.Now if the dead state comes with another state in an equiv. block finally how can it be merged?(dead state should not be merged with any other state).

Comment: Why can't the dead state be merged with other states? If other states in the DFA have no paths to any accepting state, they're effectively dead and will be merged with the dead state during minimization.

Comment: Say in an equiv. block you have states a,b,c and a dead state d.You find that a is not equiv. to b and c so ultimately two classes will be formed one of them will contain a and d and the other containing c and b.Now do you consider a and d to be equiv. and can be merged to a single state in the min. dfa?

Comment: Yep!  Unless a state ends up distinguishable from the dead state, it gets merged with the dead state.  Again, the dead state is not treated any differently from other states.